# Generating getters and setters using project Lombok

Tags: java, lombok

I wanted to use Lombok dependency in my project. So, I downloaded `lombok-1.16.18.jar` and added to the build path of on of my classes. The configuration is shown below.

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import lombok.ToString;

@ToString(includeFieldNames=true)
public @Data class Student {

@Getter
@Setter
private Integer id;

@Getter
@Setter
private String name;

//private Date dob;
@Getter
@Setter
private String uid;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Student s = new Student();
    System.out.println(s);


}
}
```

But, I am not getting proper output in console. I am getting `Object` classes `toString()` output like `com.selflearn.sandesha.Student@7852e922`
. I am also not able to use getters and setters. How to make Lombok work or what wrong I am doing?

Comment: are you using maven?

Comment: No. It is a simple java project. But I added the jar to the class path. Thank you.

Comment: What is your IDE Eclipse, Netbeans, Intellij Idea?

Comment: @GhostCat I put that vote request just because I need the answer very urgently. Sorry, If you took it in a wrong way.

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera I am using eclipse IDE. Thank you.

Comment: If you add to main the line `s.setName("foo");` do It compile?

Comment: @DavidPérezCabrera No, it did not compile. Thank you.

Comment: Did you install it in Eclipse? You need to double click the jar and it will open an installation menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks for your help. In eclipse IDE, I was not exporting the `lombok` jar. Even though, I added jar to the build path, it seems I should export it to the project in `order and export` section of eclipse.

So, In eclipse editor,

> right click on your project --> `Build Path`--> `Configure Build Path...`-->select `order and export` tab and check the jar you want to export to your project.

Or

you can also simply run the downloaded jar. This will detect the possible IDE's in the system and configure it to support all `lombok` features.

This solved my issue. Again thank you for your support.

Answer (score 2):

Your configuration is incomplete. Review https://projectlombok.org/setup/eclipse and check if It compiles. 
When it does, try again!

Answer (score 2):

If you use netbeans go to properties->Build->compiling for checked the option Enable Annotation processing

or search this option in your editor

Comment: Found it in IntelliJ when I went into Settings (Ctrl + Alt + S) -> Build,Execution,Deployment -> Compiler -> Annotation Processors. Then just clicked on the Enable annotation processing.
Thanks alot :)

Answer (score 0):

Simply download the lombok-1.18.24.jar(any version) and once download, double click on that file, so it checks your system and detects the IDE's that are available on your system. Then verify the IDE's and click on install/update button. Once the above process is completed, restart your IDE maybe, sts or eclipse.

Answer (score -1):

@Data on class level would be sufficient. Maybe it is a problem that you have put the @Data annotation between `public` and `class`.

Other question is whether your lombok.jar is on the classpath.

If I would rewrite your class, I would come up with the following:

```
@Data
public class Student {

private Integer id;

private String name;

private String uid;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Student s = new Student();
    System.out.println(s);


}
}
```

Comment: @Data we can use both ways.